# Getting doc tag names while iterating the elements

Tags: java, dom

i have this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

<root>
<items>
    <item1>
    <tag1>1</tag1>
    <tag2>2</tag2>  
    <tag3>3</tag3>
    </item1>

    <item2>
    <tag1>4</tag1>
    <tag2>5</tag2>  
    <tag3>6</tag3>
    </item2>
</items>
</root>
```

I want to iterate the item elements (item1, item2...), and for each tag get the **tag name** and after that the **value of the tag**.

I am using DOM parser.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but this ain't an unsolvable or complicated problem, this is simply reading a [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) which can be googled within seconds.

And of course, you might also check the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html), which will give you a hint about [this handy method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getNodeName%28%29) called "getNodeName()".